# Trying to understand "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" error message

Tags: python, json, pandas

```
### This line works fine
health_data_json = resp.json()["data"]["metrics"]

### This line produces "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" 
energy_data_json = resp.json()["data"]["metrics"]["basal_energy_burned"]

### This line works fine
steps_data_json = resp.json()["data"]["metrics"][1]

### Also works fine
steps_data_json2 = resp.json()["data"]["metrics"][1]["data"]
```

I am trying to better understand how to properly access data in Python and finding that I sometimes get error messages that I don't really understand why compared to other lines of code that appear similar/identical but do not produce errors.  I've provided a snippet above of some code to read a JSON file.  In the first line, I'm able to use the names of fields twice to return specific portions of the JSON.

But when I try to go a third level deep, I can no longer do that and have to pull the data using the integer index.  Then I'm again able to use the name field successfully on the 4th level to retrieve another portion of the JSON.

Why does this behave this way and what are the best ways to avoid/prevent these types of situations?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all of the helpful comments so far I wanted to share a snippet of the JSON to ask for suggestions on a better way to access the data rather than by numeric index in the event that the format were to change, is there a way I could leverage the name filed shown here:

```
{
  "data" : {
    "metrics" : [
      {
        "units" : "kcal",
        "name" : "basal_energy_burned",
        "data" : [
          {
            "date" : "2022-01-01 00:00:00 -0800",
            "source" : null,
            "qty" : 2254.3233141492697
          },
```

Comment: Maybe you should show the resp.json

Comment: A JSON data structure may contain a dict or list whose values are dicts, lists and/or plain types like strings arbitrarily nested. Here you access a dict with a value being a dict with a value being a list.

Comment: @programandoconro - I think I see what you are getting at that the structure of the JSON matters in terms of how it can be accessed.   And in my case the 3rd level doesn't match the same structure is levels 1 and 2

Answer (score 1):

`resp.json()["data"]["metrics"]` is a list.  Therefore you cannot apply the index `["basal_energy_burned"]` to it.  You must use numeric indexes like `[1]`.

I think the real question here is why you *expected* it to be otherwise.  Yes, the first and second level items are dictionaries, but so what?  The website is free to return a response in whatever format it chooses.

Comment: Thank you, (and everyone else) for these explanations.  I think that I need to spend more time analyzing the JSON format of what's returned before pointing the finger at how python accesses it.